# Back up all what app chats as text file and not as what app backup

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I want to backup whats app chat messages as text file.

I tried to open whatapp backup but it wont open as text.

I tried to export whatsapp message to mail, the problem is that it work only for one conversion chat and not all chats.

How can i back up all messages as text file(or files)?